# mongoose how to get total number of groups for pagination

Tags: mongoose, pagination, mongodb-query, grouping, aggregation

I want to implement paginaion on an array returned by the following query:

```
const aggregationQuery : any[]= [
      { 
        $match: filter
      },
      { 
        $group: {
          _id: '$reqID',
          docs:{
            $first: {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "reqID": "$reqID",
                "userID": "$userID",
                "sharerID": "$sharerID",
                "createdAt": "$createdAt",
                "destination": "$destination"
              }
            },
          },
        },
    { $sort: { _id: -1 }},
    { $skip: startingIndex }, 
    { $limit: pageSize }
];

const transfers: IPaginatedTransfer[] = await transferModel.aggregate(aggregationQuery);
```

`startingIndex` and `pageSize` are the indicators for the page I want.
The query works, however I want to also know the total number of pages given the page size (in other words, the total number of objects in the array without skip and limit).

Is there an efficient way to implement it  while avoiding querying for the full array and getting it's length?

note: a simple `countDocuments` is not what I am looking for because I want the count after grouping.

Comment: use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/#pipe._S_facet) stage and separate result, `{ $facet: { result: [ { $skip: startingIndex },  { $limit: pageSize } ], count: [ {$count: "count"} ] } }`

Answer (score 0):

So the solution we came up with was another query, just with count:

```
  static async getSize(filter: any): Promise<number> {
    const aggregationQuery : any[] = [
      {
        $match: filter
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$reqID',
        }
      },
      {
        $count: 'count'
      }];

    const transfersCount: { count: number }[] = await transferModel.aggregate(aggregationQuery);
    return transfersCount.length > 0 ? transfersCount[0].count : 0;
  }
```